# Any LDA code example in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, lda

I would like to perform simple LDA on my small data set (65x8). I have 65 instances (samples) , 8 features (attributes) and 4 classes. Any matlab code for LDA , as I know Matlab Toolbox does not have LDA function So I need to write own code. Any help?

I find on web this code

```
load /Data;
 All_data= Data(:,1:8);
 All_data_label= Data(:,9);
 testing_ind = [];
 for i = 1:length(Data)
     if rand>0.8
         testing_ind = [testing_ind, i];
         end
 end
training_ind = setxor(1:length(Data), testing_ind);

[ldaClass,err,P,logp,coeff] = classify(Data(testing_ind,:),...
    Data((training_ind),:),Data_label(training_ind,:),'linear');
[ldaResubCM,grpOrder] = confusionmat(All_data_label(testing_ind,:),ldaClass)
```

Then I got this results
ldaClass =

```
 3
 2
 3
 2
 1
 4
 3
 3
 1
 2
 1
 1
 2
```

err =

```
0.2963
```

P =

```
0.0001    0.0469    0.7302    0.2229
0.1178    0.5224    0.3178    0.0419
0.0004    0.2856    0.4916    0.2224
0.0591    0.6887    0.1524    0.0998
0.8327    0.1637    0.0030    0.0007
0.0002    0.1173    0.3897    0.4928
0.0000    0.0061    0.7683    0.2255
0.0000    0.0241    0.5783    0.3976
0.9571    0.0426    0.0003    0.0000
0.2719    0.5569    0.1630    0.0082
0.9999    0.0001    0.0000    0.0000
0.9736    0.0261    0.0003    0.0000
0.0842    0.6404    0.2634    0.0120
```

coeff =

4x4 struct array with fields:
    type
    name1
    name2
    const
    linear

ldaResubCM =

```
 4     0     0     0
 0     3     1     0
 0     1     1     0
 0     0     2     1
```

grpOrder =

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

So I have 65 Instances, 8 Attributes and 4 classes (1,2,3,4). So dont know how to interpret these results. Any help?

Comment: LDA is implemented in `classify` from the Statistics Toolbox. If you don't have it –  well, what have you tried? The [LDA formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) are straightforward to implement in Matlab. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I edit my question. I I used the classify but dont know what those results mean

Comment: I modified the question. Find a code and used the classify but not sure what I got is meanfull and how to use those results.

Comment: Your question is not really clear, but I attempted an answer. Please tell me whether this helps or not.

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation of the results derives directly from the documentation of [`classify`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classify.html).

`classify` trains a classifier based on the training data and labels (second and third argument), and applies the classifier to the test data (first argument).

`ldaClass` gives the classes chosen for the test data points, based on the classifier that has been trained using the training data points and labels.

`err` is the training error rate, the fraction of training data points that are incorrectly classified using the classifier which was trained using that data. The training error rate underestimates the error to be expected on independent test data.

`P` gives the posterior probabilities. I.e. for each test data point (rows) it gives for each class (columns) the probability that the data point belongs to that class. Probabilities sum to 1 across classes (for each row). The definite classification in `ldaClass` derives from the posterior probabilities such that for each test data point the class with the highest probability is chosen: `[~, ind] = max(P')` results in `ind = ldaClass'`.

`coeff` contains details about the trained classifier. In order to use this, you have to study in detail how the classifier works.

`confusionmat` compares the classes assigned by the classifier to the test data with the known true classes, and makes a table of the results, a [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix). Each row corresponds to the true class of a test data point, each column to the class assigned by the classifier. Numbers on the diagonal indicate correct classifications; in your result, you have a test error of `1 - sum(diag(confusionmat)) / sum(confusionmat(:))` of 0.308. In particular, the confusion matrix shows you that of the 4 test data points that belong to class two, three have been classified correctly and 1 incorrectly (as belonging to class three).

`grpOrder` just gives the explicit class labels for the four classes numbered 1 to 4; in your case, indices and labels are identical.